# Best way to handle Canary deployments with Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, devops, docker-swarm

One best-practice for microservice deployments is "Canary Deployments" (to deploy a new version of an app alongside an existing one and to get your API gateway/proxy to send a small amount of traffic to the new version until you are happy it is stable, at which point you eventually increase it to 100% and delete the old service version.)

In order to do this in Docker Swarm, it seems to me that I would need to use the version number in the name of the service to allow this side-by-side deployment e.g. `myapp_1_0_0` and `myapp_1_0_1`

The only problem with this seems to be that this will affect dns lookups both between services and also between proxy/gateway and service, which would mean that there might be a lot of complexity/api calls etc. to ensure settings are updated correctly to avoid downtime. It would be nicer to have a single dns name like `myapp` so that everything always looks for myapp and a proxy routes accordingly.

Is the only way around this to do a lot of work in the proxy and then get all the services to use the proxy for dns lookups and then stick with the versioned names? I looked at Envoy so would it make most sense to use something like that in front of the Swarm? Is there a document that anyone knows about that describes this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is **no native way** to achieve canary in docker-swarm, I tried a custom approach with [envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/) and [Envoy-Pilot](https://github.com/tak2siva/Envoy-Pilot).

Here is the step by steps to flow: https://github.com/dineshba/docker-swarm-canary

This approach will introduce:

- 1 envoy proxy container per application (as envoy is lightweight, should not be much overhead)
- Very small latency as all network will go via envoy proxy (delay(approx): 0.004 seconds (4ms))

Hope this gives you idea of how canary can be achieved in docker-swarm